# Conteúdo duplicado ao imprimir a página

Tags: html, css, media-queries

estava configurando uma página para impressão com @media print, porém ao clicar em imprimir o conteúdo aparece duplicado em duas folhas diferentes.

HTML

```
<div id="printable">CONTEÚDO</div>
```

CSS

```
@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: none; 
        filter: none;
        -ms-filter: none;
    }

    body * { visibility: hidden !important; }
    #printable, #printable * { visibility: visible !important; }
    #printable {
        position: fixed;
        left: 20px;
        top: 15px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é um comportamente padrão do position:fixed!

Veja

> fixed
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to the screen's viewport and don't move it when scrolled. **When printing, position it at that fixed position on every page.** This value always create a new stacking context.

**Resumindo Um elemento com position:fixed se repete em todas as página!**

Sugestão, aqui coloque  position: relative; e avalie. Dependendo position:absolute; pode funcionar melhor, vc vai ter que testar ai. Lembro que o padrão de position para o body é qualquer outro elemento é position: static;

```
body * { visibility: hidden !important; }
#printable, #printable * { visibility: visible !important; }
#printable {
    position: relative;
    left: 20px;
    top: 15px;
}
```

Fonte: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Entendi, mas ao mudar a position o conteúdo aparece quase no final da página, já que o  visibility: hidden apenas esconde os elementos.

Comment: @ElisOliveira como falei o motivo da duplicidade do conteúdo é o position:fixede. Agora se vc está com outro problema de aconcelho a abrir outra Pergunta e colocar seu novo problema. Essa acho que vc já sabe pq está acontecendo... Agora como vc vai fazer para corrigir não da para te ajudar sem ter mais infos. A dica foi trocar o position, se vc trocou e estragou outra coisa agora seu problema não é mais duplicidade...

Answer (score 1):

Como o Geremias falou o problema era o "position: fixed", mas como o conteúdo que eu queria imprimir estava quase no final da página e o "visibility: hidden" apenas oculta o conteúdo, tinha muito espaço em branco acima e embaixo. A solução que encontrei, embora longe de ser o ideal foi criar outra classe e colocar nas divs que não seriam exibidas, ficando assim:

```
    * {
        background: transparent;
        color: #000;
        text-shadow: none; 
        filter: none;
        -ms-filter: none;
    }
    .no_print { display: none !important; }
}
```

Valeu!!